# total combinations of divisible sums of $3$

Tags: probability, combinatorics

The first $12$ natural numbers are given. Two distinct numbers are selected. What's the probability that their sum is divisible by $3$?

This looks very easy. I know answer is $1/3$ but in spite of knowing permutations and combinations I had to find favourable cases. The numbers were few. What if we were given  question like probability that two numbers natural less than $100$ are selected and their sum is divisible by $3$? Any smart guy wouldn't go on counting. There has to be some way out which I am missing. Can you guys tell what's the best way? Thanks!

Comment: The answer is $1/3$ if the twelve numbers are consecutive.  In general, however, it depends on how many of the numbers have remainder $0$, remainder $1$, or remainder $2$.  For instance, the probability of selecting two numbers whose sum is divisible by $3$ is $1$ if each number in the set is divisible by $3$, $0$ if each number in the set has remainder $1$ when divided by $3$, and $1/2$ if the set consists of six numbers that have remainder $1$ and six numbers that have remainder $2$ when divided by $3$.

Comment: Note i have written first $12$ natural numbers and my question is different i would be pleased if you read it again

Comment: I have edited the question to make your intent clearer.

Answer (score 2):

Partition the given set $\{1,2,3, \ldots, n\}$ into three sets $A,B$ and $C$, where
\begin{align*}
A & = \{3k \, | \, k \in \mathbb{Z}\}\\
B & = \{3k+1 \, | \, k \in \mathbb{Z}\}\\
C & = \{3k+2 \, | \, k \in \mathbb{Z}\}\\
\end{align*}

Then $3 | x+y$ if and only if $(x,y) \in A \times A$ OR $(x,y) \in (B \times C) \cup (C \times B)$.

In case of $\{1,2,3, \ldots ,100\}$. $|A|=33, |B|=34$ and $|C|=33$. Now you can get the number of such $(x,y)$ pairs.

Comment: The question was about a selection of three numbers: there are four distinct combinations of remainders modulo $3$ that sum to $0$: $(0,0,0),(1,1,1),(2,2,2),(0,1,2)$

Comment: @Frentos the question says select "two" numbers. Am I missing something?

Comment: No, I misread the modified version - apologies!

Answer (score 2):

Let $a$ denote the 1st number chosen and $b$ denote the 2nd number chosen.

In order to calculate the probability that $3|a+b$, add up the following:

- $P([a\equiv0\pmod3]\wedge[b\equiv0\pmod3])=\frac{33}{100}\cdot\frac{33}{100}$
- $P([a\equiv1\pmod3]\wedge[b\equiv2\pmod3])=\frac{34}{100}\cdot\frac{33}{100}$
- $P([a\equiv2\pmod3]\wedge[b\equiv1\pmod3])=\frac{33}{100}\cdot\frac{34}{100}$

Hence the overall probability when $a$ and $b$ are chosen from $[1,100]$ is:

$$\frac{33}{100}\cdot\frac{33}{100}+\frac{34}{100}\cdot\frac{33}{100}+\frac{33}{100}\cdot\frac{34}{100}=\frac{3333}{10000}$$

---

In general, note that:

$$a,b\in[1,3n] \implies P(3|a+b)=\frac13$$